# How to count the total number of specific words in a cell and do the same for other cells as well using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I count the total number of "alt" and "first" that appeared in a cell and do the same for other cells as well while ignoring empty cells in the process? For instance, if a cell has first, first, alt, first, first, first, it should give me firstcounter = 5 (where firstcounter is the total count for first) and altcounter= 1(altcounter is the total count for alt). After that I can use the value of firstcounter and altcounter found to concatenate them into a string as shown in column B in the form of "first-" & firstcounter, "alt-"& altcounter.

```
Dim ia As Long
Dim lastrow2 As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
lastrow2 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
For ia = 2 To lastrow2
  Dim arr() As Variant
    ' Split the string to an array
arr = Split(ws1.Cells(ia, "A"), ",").Value
'what should i do after split
```

[image]

Comment: Include your own attempt on VBA please. You might be rather close to a solution. I guess you have at least found out about `Split`?

Comment: @JvdV im not sure whether did i do the split correctly as shown in my updated post but after that how do i count them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter the following into a code module...

```
Function CountWords$(r)
    Dim a&, f&, w
    For Each w In Split(r, ",")
        If w = "alt" Then a = a + 1
        If w = "first" Then f = f + 1
    Next
    If (a + f) Then CountWords = "first-" & f & ",alt-" & a
End Function
```

Then in cell `B2` enter this formula:

```
=CountWords(A2)
```

Now copy it downwards as far as you need.

---

Update

To use the above function from VBA without entering formulas in the worksheet you can do it like this...

```
Sub Cena()
    Dim i&, v
    With [a2:a8]
        v = .Value2
        For i = 1 To UBound(v)
            v(i, 1) = CountWords(v(i, 1))
        Next
        .Offset(, 1) = v
    End With
End Sub

Function CountWords$(r)
    Dim a&, f&, w
    For Each w In Split(r, ",")
        If w = "alt" Then a = a + 1
        If w = "first" Then f = f + 1
    Next
    If (a + f) Then CountWords = "first-" & f & ",alt-" & a
End Function
```

---

Update #2

In response to your questions in the comments, you can use this variation instead...

```
Sub Cena()
    Dim i&, v
    With [a2].Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
        v = .Value2
        For i = 1 To UBound(v)
            v(i, 1) = CountWords(v(i, 1))
        Next
        .Cells = v
    End With
End Sub

Function CountWords$(r)
    Dim a&, f&, w
    For Each w In Split(r, ",")
        If w = "alt" Then a = a + 1
        If w = "first" Then f = f + 1
    Next
    If (a + f) Then CountWords = "first-" & f & ",alt-" & a
End Function
```

Comment: hey thanks alot, but is there a way to make this happen after i ran the programme with VBA without having to use the additional step =CountWords(A2) step?

Comment: it works really good! Anyways as i am trying to make it possible from 2nd to lastrow, when i replaced With [a2:a8] into  With ["a2:a"&lastrow2] where lastrow2 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, it shows the object required error on  v = .Value2. Why is this so?

Comment: Also i intend to replace my  column A with the output that is found instead of showing  the output on column B tho so this means .Offset(, 1) = v is not required?

Comment: You can't use the square brackets with variables. You have to use the verbose form of Evaluate.

Comment: Nice & simple :+) FYI, posted an alternative using the `Filter()` function.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make this independent from the words *alt* and *first* and *whitespaces* in the string I would use the following functions

```
Option Explicit

'Add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Public Function RemoveWhiteSpace(target As String) As String
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "\s"
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        RemoveWhiteSpace = .Replace(target, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function

'Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Function CountWordsA(rg As Range) As String

    On Error GoTo EH

    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Set dict = New Dictionary

    Dim vDat As Variant
    vDat = RemoveWhiteSpace(rg.Value)
    vDat = Split(vDat, ",")


    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(vDat) To UBound(vDat)
        If dict.Exists(vDat(i)) Then
            dict(vDat(i)) = dict(vDat(i)) + 1
        Else
            dict.Add vDat(i), 1
        End If
    Next i


    Dim vKey As Variant
    ReDim vDat(1 To dict.Count)
    i = 1
    For Each vKey In dict.Keys
        vDat(i) = vKey & "-" & dict(vKey)
        i = i + 1
    Next vKey

    CountWordsA = Join(vDat, ",")

    Exit Function

EH:
    CountWordsA = ""

End Function

Sub TestIt()

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("A2:A8")
    Dim sngCell As Range

    For Each sngCell In rg
        sngCell.Offset(, 1) = CountWordsA(sngCell)
    Next sngCell
End Sub
```

More about [dictionaries](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) and [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

Comment: You are welcome. As said, this function is independent from the words and will also take strings like _first, second, alt , second,  alt_ with the result _first-1,second-2,alt-2_. And it will also remove whitepsaces especially blanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative using `Filter()` function**

This demonstrates the use of the `Filter()` function to count words via function `UBound()`:

**Function `CountTerms()` (usable also in formulae)**

```
Function CountTerms(ByVal WordList As String, Optional TermList As String = "first,alt", Optional DELIM As String = ",") As String
'Purpose: count found terms in wordlist and return result as list
    '[1] assign lists to arrays
    Dim words, terms
    words = Split(WordList, DELIM): terms = Split(TermList, DELIM)

    '[2] count filtered search terms
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(terms)
        terms(i) = terms(i) & "-" & UBound(Filter(words, terms(i), True, vbTextCompare)) + 1
    Next i
    '[3] return terms as joined list, e.g. "first-5,alt-1"
    CountTerms = Join(terms, ",")
End Function
```

**Example call (due to comment) & help function `getRange()`**

In order to loop over the entire range and replace the original data with the results list:

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    '[1] get range data assigning them to variant temporary array
    Dim rng As Range, tmp
    Set rng = getRange(Sheet1, tmp)       ' << change to sheet's Code(Name)

    '[2] loop through array values and get counts
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(tmp)
        tmp(i, 1) = CountTerms(tmp(i, 1))
    Next i
    '[3] write to target (here: overwriting due to comment)
    rng.Offset(ColumnOffset:=0) = tmp

End Sub

Function getRange(mySheet As Worksheet, tmp) As Range
'Purpose: assign current column A:A data to referenced tmp array
With mySheet
    Set getRange = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    tmp = getRange          ' assign range data to referenced tmp array
End With
End Function
```